# Error: "No action instance for path /login could be created" in Struts 1.3

Tags: java, jsp, struts

Why am I getting this error while iam creating helloworld application in Struts 1.3?

**login.jsp**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form name="login" action="login">
            <input type="text" >
            <input type="submit" value="submit">            
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

**struts-config.xml**

```
<action-mappings>
    <action name ="login" input= "/login.jsp" path="/login" type="com.myapp.struts.LoginAction" scope="request">
    <forward name="success" path="/success.jsp"/>
    </action>      
</action-mappings>
```

**LoginAction**

```
public class LoginAction extends org.apache.struts.action.Action {

    private static final String SUCCESS = "success";

    @Override
    public ActionForward execute(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form,
        HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws Exception {

        return mapping.findForward(SUCCESS);
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the error

Comment: Please include all the code (e.g., the package your action is declared in). The mapping seems correct assuming your JSP is at the root of the web content (JSPs should be under WEB-INF to disallow direct client access, but that's a convention, not a requirement). The form `action` should be `/login` to ensure it's at the root, but that shouldn't be causing the issue. Check your startup logs as well.